# Is the human realm the only one where conscious moral choice is possible?

Tags: karma, volition

In [this](https://personal.carthage.edu/jlochtefeld/buddhism/wheeloflife/sixrealms.html) page's explanation of the six realms of existence the human realm is presented as below, it reads a bit off.

Is it not possible, for example in the heavenly realm, to make a good choice and aim for liberation? aren't their Suttas that indicate the existence of liberated beings or of beings that are greatly cultivated and working their way for final realize in the heavenly realm?

> Human Realm
>
> The human realm is the only one in which one’s choices (good or bad)
> affect one’s future—in all the others, one is either being rewarded or
> punished for one’s actions as a human being.  One’s present human
> condition (e.g., wealth, social status, and physical and psychological
> qualities) is based on one’s past karma, but one’s present choices
> also determine one’s future (in this life, or a future life).  **As
> conscious moral agents, human beings have agency that the beings in
> other realms do not**; this clearly underscores the importance of moral
> action and spiritual development.
>
> ...

Comment: Other beings have the ability to know dhamma, but humans have a *distinct ability* for moral inclination, this is true. Humans have access to the entire range of mind realms. This affords them a unique opportunity to develop situational wisdom.

Comment: What is the "volition" tag?

Answer (score 1):

> They’ve followed those teachings by ear, reinforced them by recitation, examined them by the mind, and well comprehended them theoretically.
>
> But they die unmindful and are reborn in one of the orders of gods.
>
> Being happy there, passages of the teaching come back to them.
>
> Memory comes up slowly, but then that being quickly reaches distinction. https://suttacentral.net/an4.191/en/sujato

Not only humans.

It is also evident in that devas from the pure abodes become extinguished there.